# Scala / sbt: How to stop at breakpoints in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, debugging, sbt, breakpoints

I am trying to debug my Scala application when running tests using sbt. I have added the following lines to `build.sbt`:

```
javaOptions in test ++= Seq(
  "-Xdebug",
  "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8001"
)
```

I have also set breakpoints in Eclipse and configured a remote debugger for that port 8001.

When launching the tests from command line, the remote debugger is start correctly:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8001
```

But then the execution of the tests does not suspend, as expected, and so I am not able to connect the remote debugger. Instead, the tests are simply run.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here? How can I debug the sbt tests using breakpoints in Eclipse?

Comment: M also facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me (not tested in test, but probably work the same way). In this example, I used a project generated by udash-generator (0.3.1).

```
$ sbt
> set fork := true
> set javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xdebug",  "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8001")
> run
```

I used eclipse (Neon with ScalaIDE 4.4.1, Scala 2.11) (`sbt eclipse with-source=true`) and added a breakpoint to the `com.example.rpc.ExposedRpcInterfaces.hello(name: String)` method.

Created a run configuration:
[image: Scala debugger (Socket Attach), using Scala Remote Launcher]

Started the launch configuration (the eclipse debugger) and opened browser with `http://localhost:8080/#/rpc`, started typing to the textfield and eclipse stopped at the breakpoint.

I am not sure what was different for you, as it seems you were also forking a new JVM for tests. I can try your setup if you provide more details which test framework you were using.